# Apache Nifi : ListenHTTP vs HandleHTTPRequest

Tags: java, http, apache-nifi

What is the major difference between ListenHTTP vs HandleHTTPRequest Processor in Apache Nifi?
When will use ListenHTTP and when will use HandleHTTPRequest?

Comment: You can find a good explanation here: https://ddewaele.github.io/http-communication-with-apache-nifi

Comment: Thanks, Aydin. Its a nice reference site.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ListenHTTP alone when you are processing a stream that does not need to send answer to the caller. Rather, you will use HandleHTTPRequest in conjunction with HandleHTTPResponse to act as a web service (meaning reading a request and sending a response back). In summary :
 - Response needed => HandleHTTPRequest/HandleHTTPResponse
 - No response => ListenHTTP